# Getting Indices from Mathematica's Select

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How can I get the indices of a selection rather than the values. I.e.

```
list={3->4, 5->2, 1->1, 5->8, 3->2};
Select[list, #[[1]]==5&]; (* returns {5->2, 5->8} *)
```

I would like something like

```
SelectIndices[list, #[[1]]==5&]; (* returns {2, 4} *)
```

EDIT: I found an answer to the immediate question above (see below), but what about sorting. Say I want to sort a list but rather than returning the sorted list, I want to return the indices in the order of the sorted list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WRT to the question remaining after your edit: How about [Ordering](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ordering.html)?

```
In[26]:= Ordering[{c, x, b, z, h}]

Out[26]= {3, 1, 5, 2, 4}

In[28]:= {c, x, b, z, h}[[Ordering[{c, x, b, z, h}]]]

Out[28]= {b, c, h, x, z}

In[27]:= Sort[{c, x, b, z, h}]

Out[27]= {b, c, h, x, z}
```

Comment: It seems one can also do this: list={c,x,b,z,h}; sIdx=Sort[Range[Length[list]], list[[#1]]<list[[#2]]&]; list[[sIdx]]; Which, is basically the same as doing 
Ordering[list, Length[list], #1 < #2 &];

Comment: @quadelirus Apart from the fact that `Ordering` is about a factor of 100 faster, yes that's true. Also, `Ordering` is a very efficient function to find the position of the maximal or minimal element(s) in the list.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, well, I figured out a way to do this. Mathematica uses such a different vocabulary that searching the documentation still is generally unfruitful for me (I had been searching for things like, "Element index from Mathematica Select", to no avail.)

Anyway, this seems to be the way to do this:

```
Position[list, 5->_];
```

I guess its time to read up on patterns in Mathematica.

Comment: If searching is unsuccessful for you, you might want to try the function navigator as an alternative. Position is found in three steps there: Core language > List Manipulation > Elements of Lists. At the end you have to browse through the likely candidates, but I think you would have found `Position` quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `Ordering`:

```
Sort[list, #[[1]] == 5 &]
Ordering[list, All, #[[1]] == 5 &]
(*
{5->2,5->8,3->2,1->1,3->4}
{2,4,5,3,1}
*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had read your question to fast.

I think your second question is about how to sort the list according to the values of the rules. The simplest way that come to mind is by using a compare function. then simply use your solution to retrieve the indices:

```
comp[_ -> x_, a_ -> y_] := x < y;
Position[Sort[list, comp], 5 -> _]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Without sorting or otherwise altering the list, do this:

```
SelectIndex[list_, fn_] :=  Module[{x}, 
  x = Reap[For[i = 1, i < Length[list], i++, If[fn[list[[i]]], Sow[i], Null];]];
  If[x[[1]] == {}, {}, x[[2, 1]]]]


list={ {"foo",1}, {"bar",2}};
SelectIndex[list, StringMatchQ[ #[[1]], "foo*"] &]
```

You can use that to extract records from a database

```
Lookup[list_, query_, column_: 1, resultColumns_: All] :=  list[[SelectIndex[list, StringMatchQ[query, #[[column]]] &], resultColumns]]

Lookup(list,"foo")
```